# Pulseaudio process is not starting

Tags: pulseaudio

I have an issue with pulseaudio after replacing the motherboard the process is not starting can't even get to *Sound Settings*. The sound is working though I asume using *alsa* currently. How do I get it working again?

Here's some output from terminal:

```
:~$ pulseaudio -k
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process
:~$ sudo pulseaudio -k
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: Success
```

**UPDATE**

Answer below updated for common issues as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem was solved by simply removing *pulse* folders from `/home` directory then running `pavucontrol` in terminal successfully launched *pulseaudio* server. As I asume the issue was in one of the *pulseaudio* configuration files in *home* folder.

If it failed to create *sink input* and if you do not have any *output sound* after your PC or laptop has been suspended (hibernated) or after poweroff, using a *terminal* execute this command:

```
rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.pulse-cookie ~/.config/pulse
```

After, if it prints that some of the folders cannot be deleted because there's no such folders just wait a couple of seconds the sound shoud be back on.

if not run:

```
sudo pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

Comment: Which are the pulse folders in the home directory?

Comment: the same titled *pulse* folder in *config* folder